# JButton color won't change

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm making a reaction time game where a button will turn green and you have to hit it as fast as possible, but the button will not change colors. Can someone tell me why this is happening? Also, how could I get my program to wait until a random time (method is below) and then change color? I tried using Thread.sleep but couldn't get it to function properly.

```
mport java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    double start = System.nanoTime();
    double end;
    String startTime = String.valueOf(start);
    String endTime = String.valueOf(end);

    private JTextField displayTime = new JTextField(15);
    private JButton stopButton = new JButton("STOP");
    DecimalFormat deci = new DecimalFormat();
    Font f = new Font("ARIAL", Font.BOLD, 25);

    public Game() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        deci.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
        deci.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);


        stopButton.addActionListener(this);
        stopButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
        stopButton.setFont(f);
        stopButton.setBackground(Color.red);

        add(displayTime);
        add(stopButton);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        waitRandom();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == stopButton) {
            end = System.nanoTime();
            double time = end - start;
            double seconds = time / Math.pow(10, 9);
            String finalTime = String.valueOf(deci.format(seconds));
            displayTime.setFont(f);
            displayTime.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            displayTime.setText(finalTime + " sec.");

        }
    }

    public void waitRandom() {

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
        int randomTime = randomNumber * 100;

        stopButton.setBackground(Color.green);
        stopButton.setOpaque(true);
        System.out.println(randomTime);

    }

}
```

Comment: Does the `println()` statement run?

Comment: I don't see any waiting code here.

Comment: @APerson Yes it does, I just had that there to confirm that the number was truly random. I was using that in the Thread.sleep() method to make time when the you have to click the button random.

Comment: @immibis The Thread.sleep() method was taken out because it just stalled the program from starting.

Comment: @AlecR look at `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: my button is green Ser i didn't change anything so what is the problem do you want it not to be green

Comment: @SolomonPByer Only the border is green, but I wanted the button itself to be green

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, what "looks" like the buttons background, isn't.  It's the buttons "content", if you add

```
    stopButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

to your `waitRandom` method, you will see...

[image]

Comment: I tried his code alone and it's green what was the question please explain. i added the serialize number thats it and it works fine

Comment: @SolomonPByer Depending on the Look and Feel you are using, Swing may ignore the `background` color property of the button and "skin" it's content they way it sees fit, meaning that the button will appear not to change color.  Try using the system look and feel (like Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Doing all the UI setup in the constructor is dodgy and error-prone, but I'm going to guess that the real problem is that you're not allowing the UI to setup, render, and display on the event dispatch thread, then waiting on another thread, and then changing the color on the event dispatch thread.  You don't give us the `main()` and you don't tell us what is actually happening, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Where should I be doing my UI setup? I want to fix any bad programming practices I'm doing now before I get into the habit of it. Also, the main method is just calling a `new Game()`

Comment: Any UI changes need to be made in the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT); the methods SwingUtilities.invokeNow() and .invokeLater() are useful.  You could try calling new Game() within an invokeNow(), then waiting a random time, and then using invokeNow to change the button's color.  Your main() method is NOT on the EDT, and invokeNow() will take code and execute it on the EDT for you.

Comment: I haven't learned anything about threads so far, where can I read into them so your answer will make more sense to me?

Comment: Any basic Swing tutorial will talk about the importance of doing UI changes (like changing the color of your button) on the EDT thread.  I wouldn't worry too much about studying threads per se, just to get this program to run.  The invokeAndWait() (sorry, I got name wrong before) method is going to take a Runnable object, and execute the run() method in that object on the EDT thread.  There are plenty of examples available about creating such a Runnable object for the purpose.  Find a basic Swing tutorial and learn how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your immediate question is to add several lines of code to the end of your `if` block body in `actionPerformed()`:

```
            stopButton.setBackground(Color.red);
            paint(getGraphics());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(10) * 100);
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
            stopButton.setBackground(Color.green);
```

Now you can delete your `waitRandom()` method and its invocation from the constructor. Lastly, change the initial color, as set in the constructor, to green instead of red.

**Note** the Thread.sleep() call is a no-no here; you will want to use `javax.swing.Timer` instead. This is just to get you going in the right direction.

There's still plenty for you to figure out after this, but hopefully it sets you up.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in this: `e.getSource() == stopButton`. You should use `.equals()`

Comment: The question talks about why the button won't change color; although you came up with a bug in the event handler for the button, it (most likely) isn't related to the bug in the question.